# Android Phone is deleting the .MOV files form SD card when inserted via USB OTG

Tags: sd-card, usb-on-the-go, files, usb-c

I bought a mini camera for use when on travel and when I remove the micro SD card from the camera and insert it into the OTG USB-C adapter attached to my Note 20 Ultra, the entire contents of the VIDEO folder is deleted. I have tested it multiple times and every time it deletes all .MOV files.

The SD card is formatted for exFAT and can be read on a PC.

Comment: After removing it from camera I would test it on a PC for file-system problems. May be camera had inserted some errors into the file-system and when correcting this the file get deleted?

Comment: Just to confirm, is it only .MOV files, or the whole folder? What if you put some files with other extensions, or maybe even some random folders from the PC, then insert it into the OTG?